# Is it possible to convert text into PDF in Android?

Tags: android

I want create a PDF file through my application and want to send the PDF file as an attachment by e-mail. Is it possible in Android? If yes please show how.

Comment: @simplepi if/when you edit a post please take time to fix all the issues, not just the trivial ones.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the code

```
    Document doc = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("urgentz.pdf"));
    doc.open();
    Image image = Image.getInstance ("urgentzImageahslkdhaosd.jpg");
    doc.add(new Paragraph("Your text blah bleh"));
    doc.add(image);               
    doc.close();
```

Use the [iText](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/) library with your android project

Comment: hey its showing me error on line "Image image = Image.getInstance ("urgentzImageahslkdhaosd.jpg");" shows configure path

Answer (score 4):

1. write following dependency in gradle.build file `implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'`
2. in AndroidManifest 
   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
3. In MainActivity write following code

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
Button save;
EditText text;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT> Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            {
                if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
                {
                    String[] parmission={Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                    requestPermissions(parmission,1000);
                }
                else savepdf();
            }
            else savepdf();
        }
    });
}
private  void savepdf()
{
    Document doc=new Document();
    String mfile=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String mfilepath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+mfile+".pdf";
    Font smallBold=new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN,12,Font.BOLD);
    try{
        PdfWriter.getInstance(doc,new FileOutputStream(mfilepath));
        doc.open();
        String mtext=text.getText().toString();
        doc.addAuthor("harikesh");
        doc.add(new Paragraph(mtext,smallBold));
        doc.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+mfile+".pdf"+" is saved to "+mfilepath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"This is Error msg : " +e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case  1000:
            if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                savepdf();
            }
            else Toast.makeText(this, "parmission denied..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}`
```

Answer (score 2):

iText Library Use.
Please refer answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389994/convert-image-to-pdf-in-android).

iText sample is many. below refer site.
http://www.geek-tutorials.com/java/itext/insert_control_text.php

Comment: ya i tried that code i didn't find pdf file anywhere in my app.

Answer (score 1):

It is so simple to create the pdf

First download the droidText.0.2.jar and add in gradle file and libs folder  if you are using android studio. Then write this code for the PDF

```
public void createPDF() {
        Document doc = new Document();


        try {
            path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/ADUREC";

            File dir = new File(path);
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();

            Log.d("PDFCreator", "PDF Path: " + path);

            //This is for random name
            number = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) number.add(i);
            Collections.shuffle(number);

            File file = new File(dir, "Document" + number + ".pdf");
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);

            //open the document
            doc.open();

            Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("TENANTS : " + tenants.getText().toString());
            Font paraFont = new Font(Font.COURIER);
            p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
            p1.setFont(paraFont);

            //add paragraph to document
            doc.add(p1);

            Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("OFFFER NUMBER : " + offer_number.getText().toString());
            Font paraFont2 = new Font(Font.COURIER, 14.0f, Color.GREEN);
            p2.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
            p2.setFont(paraFont2);

            doc.add(p2);

            Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph("OFFFER NUMBER : " + offer_number.getText().toString());
            Font paraFont3 = new Font(Font.COURIER, 14.0f, Color.GREEN);
            p3.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
            p3.setFont(paraFont2);

            doc.add(p3);

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getBaseContext().getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
            myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);

//            add image to document
            doc.add(myImg);

            //set footer
            Phrase footerText = new Phrase("ADUREC DOCUMENT");
            HeaderFooter pdfFooter = new HeaderFooter(footerText, true);
            doc.setFooter(pdfFooter);

//            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success pdf", Toast
//                    .LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (DocumentException de) {
            Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + de);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PDFCreator", "ioException:" + e);
        } finally {
            doc.close();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Kotlin Sample Code:

You can use below code to create pdf pages and draw anything in canvas.

```
fun createPdf(textToPdf: String) {

    // create a new document
    val document = PdfDocument()

    // crate a page description
    var pageInfo: PdfDocument.PageInfo = PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(300, 600, 1).create()

    // start a page
    var page: PdfDocument.Page = document.startPage(pageInfo)
    var canvas = page.canvas
    var paint = Paint()
    paint.color = Color.RED
    canvas.drawCircle(50F, 50F, 30F, paint)
    paint.color = Color.BLACK
    canvas.drawText(textToPdf, 80F, 50F, paint)
    //canvas.drawt
    // finish the page
    document.finishPage(page)
    // draw text on the graphics object of the page

    // Create Page 2
    pageInfo = PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(300, 600, 2).create()
    page = document.startPage(pageInfo)
    canvas = page.canvas
    paint = Paint()
    paint.color = Color.BLUE
    canvas.drawCircle(100F, 100F, 100F, paint)
    document.finishPage(page)

    // write the document content
    val directory_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + "/mypdf/"
    val file = File(directory_path)
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs()
    }
    val targetPdf = directory_path + "test-2.pdf"
    val filePath = File(targetPdf)
    try {
        document.writeTo(FileOutputStream(filePath))
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.e("main", "error " + e.toString())
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Something wrong: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    // close the document
    document.close()
    //isPrinting = false
}
```

#### Note:

Do not forget to add [external storage write permission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33162451/1084174)