# Android studio exporting to pdf/email/something

Tags: android

I have a button on an android app I'm working that is in the same activity as a listview that I would like to export to pdf and email if I can learn one I can probably figure the other one out. Does anyone know how I should go about doing this or a tutorial that I can look at the learn it?

I google'd how to but couldn't find anything on it.

My IDE is android studio.

Comment: What do you want to export as pdf/email?

Comment: The goal will be to have a sort of guest list that the user can click one button and add people to the listview. Then click another button that says export that will let the user export the text of the list to pdf or email.

Comment: You can take  a look at this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726411/is-it-possible-to-convert-text-into-pdf-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an ACTION_SEND intent to share whatever data you choose. You can tie it to a ShareActionProvider if you want a share button to appear.