# Is it possible to convert image to pdf in android

Tags: android

Is there any sample code for converting image that take through camera to pdf file.Please help me.

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389994/convert-image-to-pdf-in-android

Answer (score 0):

check the drioidText Library [here](https://facturaelectronica.googlecode.com/svn-history/r51/trunk/lib/droidText.0.2.jar) it helps to create pdf's dynamically