# Trying to save WebView to PDF in Android is there a way i can save the captured bitmap to the pdf

Tags: android, pdf, webview

Trying to save WebView to PDF in Android is there a way i can save the captured bitmap to pdf

How to save the captured bitmap in pdf not getting with my code

Is there any way to save webview contents to PDF

Shared Code Below

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.webviewtopdf;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Picture;
import android.graphics.drawable.PictureDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView myWebView;
    Bitmap bmp;
    ImageView img;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "You PDF was Saved Successfully", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();

                myWebView.capturePicture();
            }
        });

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview);

//        myWebView.setPictureListener(new WebView.PictureListener() {
//
//            public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture) {
//                if (picture != null) {
//                    try {
//                        Bitmap bmp = pictureDrawable2Bitmap(new PictureDrawable(picture));
//                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
//                        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
//                        out.close();
//                    } catch (Exception e) {
//                        e.printStackTrace();
//                    }
//                }
//            }
//        });

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

//                Picture picture = myWebView.capturePicture();

                Picture picture = view.capturePicture();
                Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(picture.getWidth(), picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
                picture.draw(c);

                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream( "/sdcard/"  + "page.pdf" );
                    if ( fos != null ) {
                        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos );
                        fos.close();
                    }
                }
                catch( Exception e ) {
                    System.out.println("-----error--"+e);
                }

            }
        });

        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.yahoo.com");
    }

    private static Bitmap pictureDrawable2Bitmap(PictureDrawable pictureDrawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth()
                , pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight()
                , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawPicture(pictureDrawable.getPicture());
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: it has nothing to do with pdf it just capture webview and save it as image

Comment: As Selvin said, you are capturing a Bitmap not a PDF.

Comment: is there a way i can store the captured image into pdf file

Answer (score 0):

You are currently only capturing an image, which is a `BitMap` and not a PDF.

You should try and find / use 3rd party libs that can convert IMG to PDF. If found a working approach on SO answers:

- [Image to PDF using IText PDF Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305362/how-to-convert-image-to-pdf)