# Inserting image into PDF in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a project using images where the user gets to choose if they want to save in `.jpg` or `.pdf` format. So what I thought was either way save it in `.jpg` initially and then if they choose `.pdf`, just push the image into pdf. I read a lot of documentation like xfinium pdf and syncfusion pdf but sadly all those are licensed for commercial use. I was wondering if anybody could point me at the right direction so as to how to get this done without using paid licensing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44807531/7462031)

Comment: syncfusion has free community license. https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/communitylicense

Comment: There is also LGPL itext port, which now can be ported to .net standard with System.Drawing.Common https://github.com/JamieMellway/iTextSharpLGPL-MonoForAndroid

Comment: You can use the native features in iOS and Android to create PDFs

Comment: SkiaSharp seems to have PDF support. https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/releases/tag/v1.49.4-beta

Comment: This is off-topic, and I'm kinda confused as to why the moderator @christian edited the question instead of closing it.  See #4, recommending software libraries  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thanks a lot @AccessDenied I used Skiasharp to create my images I shall look into skiasharp for pdf and post here if i could complete it.

Comment: @G.hakim I am not using native method to build this project. I am using Xamarin. Thank you though.

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks for helping me out I will look into platform specific approach after trying the Skiasharp approach.

Comment: @NihalSekhar No problem, while a cross-platform solutions are nice, the native ones tend to be a little faster and of course no app size bloat since you are using the features all ready on the device... happy coding ;-)

Comment: @SushiHangover, I wouldn't make assumptions which is faster without benchmarks. Skia is a c++ library and is fast. Google chrome uses it as far as I know. Skia sharp is just a wrapper.

Comment: @AccessDenied Been there, done that ;-) ... via the native Android/iOS APIs PDF generation is faster then "SkiaSharp" (maybe not the native C++, but with the C# wrapper it sure is... did not benchmark the C++ code without the wrappers, but yes Skia itself is fast, the C# wrappers/objects and resulting GC kills the performance in many areas of SkiaSharp, then there is the memory bloat and app size issues after that...)

Comment: @Andy : To me this question reads like a clear description of a problem that the user is having. The help says "Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."
This question doesn't ask for a library but for the best way to solve the problem that the user has by reporting what research they have done. The fact that pointing the user to a library might be the best answer doesn't make it offtopic.

Comment: @Christian And yet the only answer and many of the above comments are just that; suggestions for which library to use and nothing else.  The last part about not using a paid license does seem to suggest asking for a library.

Comment: @Andy : The policy is not worded in a way that prevents certain answers that are helpful (which this answer likely is) but to force people to specify the problem that they are having. I also see neither highly opiniated answer nor spam answers or comments that the policy is intended to hinder.

Comment: @Christian The policy is very clear "Some questions are still off-topic, *even if they fit into one of the categories listed above*: Questions asking us to *recommend or find […] software library [..]* are off-topic for Stack Overflow"  I don't see any leeway there.

Comment: @Andy The question doesn't do that directly. It rather talks about the problem and that's the recommended way by the policy to address the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use: [PdfSharpCore](https://github.com/ststeiger/PdfSharpCore)
is a partial port of [PdfSharp.Xamarin](https://github.com/roceh/PdfSharp.Xamarin/) for .NET Standard.