# Creating Android PDF file using two two Activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have two Activities, Activity_1 and Activity_2.

In Activity_1, I have an ImageView and a Button called "Go to Next".

In Activity_2, I have a Button called "CreatePDF".

So, I just want to know how to create a PDF with an image from Activity_1 when I press the CreatePDF button in Activity_2.

I would thankful if any one can solve this.

Thank You

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305362/how-to-convert-image-to-pdf Check this linkout

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert Image to PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305362/how-to-convert-image-to-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

From the few details you are giving here, I assume the `Activity_2` does not know the image you want to export.

So first, you need to pass a reference to the image, or the image data itself, from `Activity_1` to `Activity_2`.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519691/passing-image-from-one-activity-another-activity) which may have what you're looking for.

The accepted answer is suggesting to use one of these three solutions:

- Convert the image from `Bitmap` to `byte` array, then pass this `byte` array from one activity to another using an `Intent` object.
- Save the image to the SD Card (or anywhere on the phone) and pass the image file path as a `string` from one activity to another, using an `Intent` object.
- Pass the `Bitmap` image using an `Intent` object, without converting it.

I hope this helps.