# Recyclerview list to pdf

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pdf-generation

I have a recyclerview data is set from server i want to save the data to pdf file
how can i achieve please help

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jobj.getJSONArray("Complaint Details");
rcview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bbg1);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    jobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    viewcmplist item = new viewcmplist(
            jobj.getString("subject"),
            jobj.getString("mark"),
            jobj.getString("ce"),
            jobj.getString("te"),
            jobj.getString("grade")

    );
    listitems1.add(item);
}
cmpadapter = new CmpviewAdapter(listitems1, getApplicationContext());
rcview.setAdapter(cmpadapter);
```

Comment: i didnt tried  i don't know how to start......

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom library such as https://github.com/HendrixString/Android-PdfMyXml. I prefer this library than any other method. Just Go through these.

but there is another way  -
 [How to convert Android View to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29730402/how-to-convert-android-view-to-pdf) - that generate a pdf that contains bitmap of your layout